# name 'category_id' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to get the id of the category but this error keeps up poping.
Here is my **models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='category_created')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='product')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    available = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is my views where by errors is occuring from and don't know how to fix the views and i am sure the problem is from my **views.py**

```
@login_required
def product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category.objects.get(pk = category_id)
        product_form = ProductForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if product_form.is_valid():
            new_item = product_form.save(commit=False)
            new_item.category = category
            new_item.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Product created')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Product Failed to be created')
    else:
        product_form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'shop/product/product_create.html', {'product_form':product_form})
```

Comment: Well, indeed it is not defined. Where is that supposed to be coming from?

Comment: You are trying to use a variable `category_id` in your view, but that variable has not been defined anywhere, hence the error.

Comment: That is obviously up to you. You've said "give me the Category related to this ID". But *where are you intending to get that ID from*?

Comment: Do you have this error because `categpry_id` is not defined on `category = Category.objects.get(pk = category_id)` . Just read error code and use intantiated vars.

Comment: Right. But for the third time, where is the ID going to come from? How will your code know what category to use?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ekhorutomwen Harsley,

If you try to create a new object, you don't need this id because Django added it automatically.

you just have to create a new Category object by something like that

```
    @login_required
def product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category()
        product_form = ProductForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if product_form.is_valid():
            new_item = product_form.save(commit=False)
            new_item.category = category
            new_item.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Product created')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Product Failed to be created')
    else:
        product_form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'shop/product/product_create.html', {'product_form':product_form})
```

If you want to access a category which already exists in your database. You can access it in this way :

```
category_id = 3 // the id you want to access
category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
```

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

you should have to use a static id or
you should have to use a id from post method

```
 @login_required
def product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #category_id = 1
        #you should have to use a static id
        #category_id = request.POST['category_id']
        #you should have to use a id from post method 
        category = Category.objects.get(pk = category_id)
        product_form = ProductForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if product_form.is_valid():
            new_item = product_form.save(commit=False)
            new_item.category = category
            new_item.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Product created')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Product Failed to be created')
    else:
        product_form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'shop/product/product_create.html', {'product_form':product_form})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
category = Category.objects.get(pk = category_id)
```

To be able to get the `Category` object identified by `category_id`, `category_id` must be defined. Your view function (`product()`) does not define this variable.

I understand you are trying to create a `Product` using the form data. If the form contains a field for the relationship between `Product` and `Category`, you don't need to manually set `product.category`.

If `ProductForm` does not have a filed for the relationship, then you have to get the `category_id` either from the form in the `request` object (assuming you have that field in the HTML form) like:

```
category_id = request.POST.get('category_id')
```

or passing the category ID as a URL parameter ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups))